# Logical trees: difference between Before Project Normalization and Join Collapsed

Tags: sql-server, optimization

The Before Project Normalization tree follows the Join Collapsed tree.

Using a sample set of ~250 queries - and Traceflags 8605, 8606, 8607, 3604 - I have not detected any difference between these two trees, in any of the sample queries.

Is it possible to construct a query where there is a difference between those two trees?

(This is research for a blog post - I will credit anyone who can help.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to construct a query where there is a difference between those two trees?

No.

The sequence of events is:

- The *Join-collapsed Tree* is printed immediately after *Heuristic Join Reordering*.
- Memory usage before project normalization is printed (if enabled).
- *Normalize Projects* is called.

  - If project normalization has been disabled, it exits.
  - Otherwise, a call to *Derive Group Properties* is made.
  - Nothing has been added or changed, so properties are not rederived.
  - *Normalize Projects* prints the *Tree Before Project Normalization*.

---

The extra call to *Derive Group Properties* has almost zero cost if no work needs to be done. One can only speculate *why* the tree is debug printed on *entry* to *Normalize Projects*.